# T-SQL Scientific notation field conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I load excel file into sql as `varchar(max)` and got that Scientific  `e` value which now I try to convert into `numeric` as I need to do compare that value, and here I'm running into problem.

This is main question:  How  and to what type I can convert this to compare with whole integer  value ?

On the pic You can see how this seen in Excel, even formatted to text it somehow still loaded into varchar(max) not like char string. This can be seen from my test code.

[image]

```
DECLARE @C VARCHAR(MAX) = '1.1001562717e+011', @Nc VARCHAR(MAX) = '110015627174';  
SELECT @c, LEN(@c) LenC , 
      ISNUMERIC(@c) NumYN
---,  CAST(@c AS DECIMAL(38,2)) cDec   ---CAST(@c AS NUMERIC) cNum  --, CAST(@c AS BIGINT) cInt
WHERE @c LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
  AND ISNUMERIC(@c) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, `ISNUMERIC` is a terrible function, it does not give good results; it is often wrong. If you try `ISNUMERIC('1.1001562717e+011')` you'll notice that you get the value `1`, however, `CONVERT(numeric(13,1),'1.1001562717e+011')` will produce an error. A far better function is `TRY_CONVERT` (or `TRY_CAST`), which returns `NULL` if the conversion fails for the **specific** data type: `TRY_CONVERT(numeric(13,1),'1.1001562717e+011')`.

Being specific on the data type is actually important here, as `ISNUMERIC` could be (incorrectly) suggesting that the value could be converted to at least 1 of the numeric data types; but that doesn't mean all of them. For scientific data types the only data type you can convert to is a `float`/`real`:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(numeric(13,1),'1.1001562717e+011') AS Numeric,
       TRY_CONVERT(bigint,'1.1001562717e+011') AS int,
       TRY_CONVERT(float,'1.1001562717e+011') AS float,
       TRY_CONVERT(money,'1.1001562717e+011') AS money;
```

Notice that only `float` has a value here. As you want a `numeric` as the final value, then you'll need to `CONVERT` the value twice:

```
CONVERT(numeric(13,1),TRY_CONVERT(float,'1.1001562717e+011'))
```

Comment: The leading `1`, to the left of the radix point, in the OP's example got dropped from your sample code. The OP's value needs a `numeric(13,1)`, not 12. Or it could be two-step converted to a `BigInt` if the value will always be an integer. Since a `BigInt` offers more significant digits than a `float(53)` there shouldn't be a problem unless the OP has integers with a lot of trailing zeros.

Comment: You're right, @HABO ,must have missed the leading one when I copied the value. Will fix

Comment: Hi Larnu, Isnumeric was in question for me too, but it confirmed with like [0-9] so somehow sql know it's Numeric.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` doesn't check if a value just has the characters `[0-9]` @Mich28 . But, like I said, don't use it, it's not trust worthy.

Comment: Tx, all. Iit's all clear in SQL, now I go to original Excel to see if I can improve it inthere.